# How to return Switch-Case to main program

Tags: java

My program computes the speed of sound after the user inputs the distance and the medium it's passing through (air,water,earth,steel). I just need to know how to return to my main program after a computation is done if the user inputs yes or stop the program (break I assume), if they input no.

```
System.out.print(" What is the distance in feet:" );
//ask the user to input variables

while (!keyboard.hasNextDouble()) {
    System.out.println("Please enter a valid numeric value, try again: ");
    keyboard.next();
}
Distance =keyboard.nextDouble();
{
    System.out.print("Input the media: Air, Water, Steel, or Earth: ");
    String Input = keyboard.next();

    switch(Input.toLowerCase()) {

        case "air":
            AirSpeed = Distance/Air;
            System.out.print("\n \nThe time to for sound to travel ");
            System.out.print(Distance);
            System.out.print(" feet through AIR" +"\n");
            System.out.printf("%.6f", AirSpeed);
            System.out.print(" seconds or ");
            System.out.printf("%.1f", OneFootPerSecond*Air);
            System.out.print(" miles per hour."); 
            System.out.print("\n \nEnter Yes for another calculation, else No: ");
            String Another = keyboard.next();
            Another.toLowerCase();

            break;

        case "water":
            WaterSpeed = Distance/Water;
            System.out.print("\nThe time to for sound to travel ");
            System.out.print(Distance);
            System.out.print(" feet through WATER" +"\n");
            System.out.printf("%.6f",WaterSpeed);
            System.out.print(" seconds or ");
            System.out.printf("%.1f", OneFootPerSecond*Water);
            System.out.print(" miles per hour."); 
            System.out.print("\n \nEnter Yes for another calculation, else No: ");
            Another = keyboard.next();
            Another.toLowerCase();

            break;

        case "steel":
            SteelSpeed = Distance/Steel;
            System.out.print("\nThe time to for sound to travel ");
            System.out.print(Distance);
            System.out.print(" feet through STEEL" +"\n");
            System.out.printf("%.6f",SteelSpeed);
            System.out.print(" seconds or ");
            System.out.printf("%.1f", OneFootPerSecond*Steel);
            System.out.print(" miles per hour."); 
            System.out.print("\n \nEnter Yes for another calculation, else No: ");
            String Another = keyboard.next();
            Another.toLowerCase();

            break;

        case "earth":
            EarthSpeed = Distance/Water;
            System.out.print("\nThe time to for sound to travel ");
            System.out.print(Distance);
            System.out.print(" feet through EARTH" +"\n");
            System.out.printf("%.6f",EarthSpeed);
            System.out.print(" seconds or ");
            System.out.printf("%.1f", OneFootPerSecond*Earth);
            System.out.print(" miles per hour."); 
            System.out.print("\n \nEnter Yes for another calculation, else No: ");
            String Another = keyboard.next();
            Another.toLowerCase();

            break;

        // TODO code application logic here
        default :
            System.out.print("Invalid. Re-run the program. ");

            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you mean that after the switch statement is executed, your program ends? And you want it to run again?

Comment: Yes, I ask the user if they want to do another calculation. If they say yes then start the program over and if not then end the program.

Comment: If you ask better questions, you'll get better answers. You code example is not complete and is cluttered with stuff that is not relevant to the question. I'm guessing that your code is all within the `main` method, if so you should include the surrounding main method. But you should also exclude things that are working fine and aren't relevant, like your calculation logic.See this guide: http://sscce.org/

Comment: Suggest planning your program structure and logic first - it's not necessary to repeat all these lines if you have one method that does that stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I gathered that you want to keep repeating the switch statement if the user indicates that they  would like to continue. In that case, you need to wrap the switch statement in a loop which keeps looping until the user says "No". Consider the following example:

```
boolean shouldContinue = true;

while (shouldContinue == true){

    switch(Input.toLowerCase()) {

        case "earth":
            //calculate speed...

            System.out.print("\n \nEnter Yes for another calculation, else No: ");
            String Another = keyboard.next();
            Another.toLowerCase();

            //If the user inputs 'no', we change shouldContinue, that stops the loop from executing again
            if (Another.equals("no"){
                shouldContinue = false;
            }
        break;



         case "water":
            //calculate speed...

            System.out.print("\n \nEnter Yes for another calculation, else No: ");
            Another = keyboard.next();
            Another.toLowerCase();

            //If the user inputs 'no', we change shouldContinue, that stops the loop from executing again
            if (Another.equals("no"){
                shouldContinue = false;
            }
        break;

         case "steel":
            //calculate speed...

            System.out.print("\n \nEnter Yes for another calculation, else No: ");
            String Another = keyboard.next();
            Another.toLowerCase();

            //If the user inputs 'no', we change shouldContinue, that stops the loop from executing again
            if (Another.equals("no"){
                shouldContinue = false;
            } 
           break;     

        case "earth":
            //calculate speed...

            System.out.print("\n \nEnter Yes for another calculation, else No: ");
            String Another = keyboard.next();
            Another.toLowerCase();

            //If the user inputs 'no', we change shouldContinue, that stops the loop from executing again
            if (Another.equals("no"){
                shouldContinue = false;
            } 
       break;

        default :
            System.out.print("Invalid. Re-run the program. ");
            shouldContinue = false;    
        break;
   }
}
```

Some other notes about your code:

You're not following the [java naming conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconventions-135099.html#367) for your variables. All variable names should start with a lower case letter. This is a simple cosmetic change that makes your code much easier to read.

> Except for variables, all instance, class, and class constants are in
>   mixed case with a lowercase first letter

Arguably, you're also putting too much code in one place, you should try to improve your code by moving some of it to separate (reusable) methods.

Comment: Yes you gathered correctly. Also as far as naming convention I will definitely keep note of that. Your suggestion works, all that's left is I need to make the program run again starting from the point where it asks for the distance if shouldContinue = yes, that's it! Thank you for your help by the way, I cannot thank you enough!

Comment: Great! You would just need to move more code under the while loop! If this answer helped, would you please consider marking it as the accepted answer? Thank you! You can do that by clicking the white tick next to my answer

Comment: So close, everything works except I need to make it so that the program will ask the user to try again if either yes or no is not entered. I will gladly accept your answer if you can just give me a heads up on this please!

Comment: You would need another loop - this time, around the "Enter Yes for another calculation, else No" question. Something like this:

do {
System.out.print("\n \nEnter Yes for another calculation, else No: ");
            Another = keyboard.next();
            Another.toLowerCase();

            //If the user inputs 'no', we change shouldContinue, that stops the loop from executing again
            if (Another.equals("no"){
                shouldContinue = false;
                break;
            }
            else if (Another.equals("yes"){
                break;
            }

}

Answer (score -1):

You need to invoke that method (with the switch in it) from inside some kind of loop. e.g.

```
public static void main() {


    //start loop

    //invoke method containing switch statement.

    //endloop

    }
```

Otherwise you switch is executed, and then there's nothing left to do and the program ends.

Perhaps try:

```
while(true) {
  //invoke switch code containing switch statement
}
```

You'll have to manually force quit, and then if it does what you want try to make it exit gracefully on command (don't want to hint TOO much).